Positive 〜る to 〜らん conjugation?
I'm playing the game 'Hades' and came across:

ハデス神の名において、オリュンポスの神の御言葉を賜らん！

The character seems to be requesting/demanding/etc the words of the gods, so why is 賜る conjugated to 賜らん?
This game is originally in English, and I believe I read in an article that the Japanese version had some questionable translations.
However, when I plug this sentence into translation apps it still retains its positive form.
Is this some archaic conjugation?
